# Not able to deploy SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

When trying to deploy the package, got the error like below: Please help

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "encrypt_binarydata": 
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. 
Not enough storage is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)
System.IO.FileLoadException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.Security.CryptoGraphy.CreateSymmetricKey(String algorithm)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.Security.CryptoGraphy.EncryptBinaryData(SqlString algorithmName, SqlBytes key, SqlBytes IV, SqlBytes binaryData)
. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 6522)
```

I want to successfully deploy the package

Comment: How are you deploying the package (.dtsx) or are you deploying a project (.ispac). This looking interesting `Not enough storage is available to process this command`

Comment: I am deploying the whole project. It has two .dtsx packages.Thank You

Comment: Also, I tried to export the existing same package from SSISDB(SSMS) to see any differences between the new version and old version, it gave me the same error. I am confused.

Comment: Great, project deployment model. What is the specific mechanism you are using to deploy the project? Are you right clicking in Visual Studio to deploy? Are you double clicking a .ispac file? Have you written custom scripts to do this? What version of SSIS are you dealing with? What version of SQL Server is the target server running?

Comment: To Deploy the project:  Right click on the project, deploy use Integration Services Deployment Wizard.                                                                                                                    No custom scripts, just the wizard to deploy the project.The sql server on the target server is 2012 and I have mentioned in the SSIS package Project properties as SQLServer 2012 in DeploymentTargetVersion field.

Comment: Also, the Visual Studio on my machine is 2019 and on the server is very old.